# Forcestop GlobalSearch function in matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization

I'm having an issue with an optimization problem. I think the code works fine, but I would like to force-stop it when it has reached a few optimal values(under 1e-11). The only solution I have found so far is to set MaxTime to 120

```
optionsMS = ptimoptions(@fmincon,'MaxIter',1000000,'MaxFunEvals',1000000,...
     'Algorithm','sqp');
problem = createOptimProblem('fmincon','lb',LB,'ub',UB,'x0',vx,...
     'options',optionsMS,...
     'objective',@(v)opti(v,x0,N,imag(wFs),imag(wPs),epsilon,R,W));
gs=GlobalSearch('Display','iter','StartPointsToRun','bounds','MaxTime',120);

[x3,fval3] = run(gs,problem)
```

What else could I do?

EDIT:
I have set TolFun to 1e-11

```
optionsGS = optimoptions(@fmincon,'MaxIter',1000000,'MaxFunEvals',1000000,...
     'Algorithm','interior-point','TolFun',1e-11);
```

And these are the results

```
 Num Pts                 Best       Current    Threshold        Local        Local                 
Analyzed  F-count        f(x)       Penalty      Penalty         f(x)     exitflag        Procedure
       0     2961    0.006034                                0.006034            2    Initial Point
     200    16921    0.006034                                 0.01213            2    Stage 1 Local
     300    17023    0.006034         6.352        1.086                              Stage 2 Search
     400    17123    0.006034         6.322        4.191                              Stage 2 Search
     432    26074   4.379e-13         6.228        6.475    4.379e-13            2    Stage 2 Local
     433    35845   4.379e-13         6.205        6.228    4.244e-13            2    Stage 2 Local
     434    44004   4.379e-13         1.995        6.205      0.01337            2    Stage 2 Local
     435    52661   3.944e-13         1.514        1.995    3.944e-13            2    Stage 2 Local
     474    54906   3.944e-13         1.939        2.017      0.01789           -1    Stage 2 Local

GlobalSearch stopped because maximum time is exceeded.

GlobalSearch called the local solver 7 times before exceeding 
the clock time limit (MaxTime = 120 seconds).
6 local solver runs converged with a positive local solver exit flag.
```

Three results are below 1e-11 so I think it should stop but I dont know how to set that on the *optimoptions*.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `TolFun` or `TolX` value for your `ptimoptions`, depending on what your stopping criteria is.

If you want to set a lower bound on the size step, go for `TolX`. If your goal is to constrain the lower bound in the change of the objective function, set `TolFun` instead. [The Matlab documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/tolerances-and-stopping-criteria.html) has a nice graph showing the difference between them:

[image: tolfuntoilx]

I believe you are looking for the `TolFun` option. That being said, besides changing the `MaxTime`, you could try the following:

```
optionsMS = ptimoptions(@fmincon,'MaxIter',1000000,'MaxFunEvals',1000000,...
     'Algorithm','sqp','TolFun',1e-11);
```

Comment: I have tried it and it doesnt stop, I have edited the first post with the output.